# progress dialog master-detail not showing android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an asynctask which accesses data from a server and populates a master-detail flow. Populating the list on the left-hand side. I can see the progress dialog working fine. When I select that item, I then call another async task to get more information for that side. When I select the item from the list on the left-hand side, the progress dialog doesn't show. It pops up for like a split second and then the data is shown.

How can I create a progress dialog that shows up for the duration of the second asynctask getting data for the right hand fragment?

**Left hand list item:**

```
public class ItemListFragment extends ListFragment 
{

private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private String message = "";
private Socket client;
private XMLCreator x = new XMLCreator();


private static final String STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION = "activated_position";

private Callbacks mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;

private int mActivatedPosition = ListView.INVALID_POSITION;

public interface Callbacks 
{

    public void onItemSelected(int id, String value);
}


private static Callbacks sDummyCallbacks = new Callbacks() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(int id, String value) 
    {
    }
};

public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, ArrayList<String>> 
{

    ProgressDialog PD;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
       //Works fine and shows up perfectly
       super.onPreExecute();
       PD = new ProgressDialog(ItemListFragment.this.getActivity());
       PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
       PD.setMessage("Loading...");
       PD.setCancelable(true);
       PD.setIndeterminate(true);
       PD.show();
      }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Integer... params) 
    {
        Socket client;
        DataInputStream input;
        DataOutputStream output;
        String serverResult = "nothing";
        XMLCreator x = new XMLCreator();
        ArrayList<String> lists = new ArrayList<String>();;

        try 
        {
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Client started");

            // Step 1: Create a Socket to make connection.
            // client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 500);
            client = new Socket("10.0.0.5", 5001);
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Connected to: "
                    + client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            publishProgress("Connecting to server...");

            // Step 2: Get the input and output streams.
            input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            output.flush();
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Got I/O Streams");
            publishProgress("Obtained Streams...");

                // Step 3: Process connection.

            // Step 4: Close connection.
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Transmission complete. "
                    + "Closing connection.");
            output.writeUTF("TERMINATE");
            client.close();
            publishProgress("Closed connection...");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            String s = e.getMessage();
            String b = s;
        }
        return lists;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> lists) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(lists);
        PD.dismiss();
        List<DummyItem> ITEMS = new ArrayList<DummyItem>();
        for (String s : lists)
        {
            int count = 1;
            ITEMS.add(new DummyItem("",s));
        }
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<DummyContent.DummyItem>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1, android.R.id.text1, ITEMS));

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
    {
        PD.setMessage(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}


public ItemListFragment() 
{
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ConnectToServer task = new ConnectToServer();
    task.execute();

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    // Restore the previously serialized activated item position.
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION)) {
        setActivatedPosition(savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) 
{
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // Activities containing this fragment must implement its callbacks.
    if (!(activity instanceof Callbacks)) 
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Activity must implement fragment's callbacks.");
    }

    mCallbacks = (Callbacks) activity;
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();

    // Reset the active callbacks interface to the dummy implementation.
    mCallbacks = sDummyCallbacks;
}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position, long id) 
{
    super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, id);

    Object item = listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

    String myitem = item.toString();

    mCallbacks.onItemSelected(position, myitem);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) 
{
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    if (mActivatedPosition != ListView.INVALID_POSITION) 
    {

        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVATED_POSITION, mActivatedPosition);
    }
}

public void setActivateOnItemClick(boolean activateOnItemClick) 
{

    getListView().setChoiceMode(activateOnItemClick ? ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE : ListView.CHOICE_MODE_NONE);
}

private void setActivatedPosition(int position) 
{
    if (position == ListView.INVALID_POSITION) 
    {
        getListView().setItemChecked(mActivatedPosition, false);
    } else 
    {
        getListView().setItemChecked(position, true);
    }

    mActivatedPosition = position;
    }
 }
```

**Right hand details fragment:**

```
public class CountingFragment extends Fragment 
{
int mNum;
String value;
List<Session> lists;
String[] simpleArray;

public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<Session>> 
{

    ProgressDialog PD;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
       //Doesn't show up at all ---> Want to show the dialog here
       PD = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
       PD.setTitle("Please Wait..");
       PD.setMessage("Loading...");
       PD.setCancelable(true);
       PD.setIndeterminate(true);
       PD.show();
       super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Session> doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        Socket client;
        DataInputStream input;
        DataOutputStream output;
        String results = "";
        XMLCreator x = new XMLCreator();
        List<Session> items = new ArrayList<Session>();
        try 
        {
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Client started");

            // Step 1: Create a Socket to make connection.
            // client = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(), 500);
            client = new Socket("10.0.0.5", 5001);
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Connected to: "
                    + client.getInetAddress().getHostName());
            publishProgress("Connected...");

            // Step 2: Get the input and output streams.
            input = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            output = new DataOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Got I/O Streams");
            publishProgress("Obtained Streams...");

                // Step 3: Process connection.
            //Read in the value that the user selected from the bundle
            String Day = params[0].toString();

            // Step 4: Close connection.
            Log.i("CLIENT", "Transmission complete. "
                    + "Closing connection.");
            output.writeUTF("TERMINATE");
            client.close();
            publishProgress("Closed connection...");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return items;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Session> lists) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(lists);
        PD.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
    {
        PD.setMessage(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);

    }
}

/**
 * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num" as an argument.
 */
static CountingFragment newInstance(int num, String value) 
{
    CountingFragment f = new CountingFragment();

    // Supply num input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("num", num);
    args.putString("value", value);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

/**
 * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
    value = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getString("value") : "";

    ConnectToServer task = new ConnectToServer();
    try 
    {
        lists = task.execute(value).get();


    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its instance number.
 */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_world, container, false);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_sessions);
    final SessionAdapter adapter = new SessionAdapter(getActivity(), lists);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    //ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(  
          //   inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,  
          //   lists);            
    return view;
  }
}
```

Is there any specific reason as to why my progress dialog is not showing up on select of the list item??? Where am I going wrong in my code??

Comment: Typical reasons would be that you are not doing so on the UIThread and therefore it doesn't happen, or the code is being executed too quickly within the doInBackground() and not visual aide is shown.

Answer (score 0):

you can't getActivity() from AsyncTask, you should pass it in the constructor:

first add constructor

```
public ConnectToServer(Activity activity) {
    super();
    this.activity = activity;
}
```

then use the activity in your dialog

```
PD = ProgressDialog.show(activity,"title","massage", true);
PD.setCancelable(true);
PD.show();
```

Comment: Then in my instantiation I would call? ConnectToServer task = new ConnectToServer(getActivity());